# Is there a word or a phrasal verb that describes the action of covering your head for protection?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

Is there a word or a phrasal verb that describes the action of covering your head for protection? I am not sure if this is warranted but "covering your head with both of your hands" is a mouthful, so I was wondering if it was possible to shorten it.

Comment: Do you mean to get down?

Comment: just the upper arm movements

Comment: "Duck and cover" is what it's called when you both get down and cover your head, but you can't just use "cover" by itself.

Comment: There is no single word for this action.  The common phrase is to *"cover one's head with one's hands/arms"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shield:
a person or thing providing protection.

"John was like a human shield, jumping in between the attackers and the unsuspecting victim"

synonyms:   protection, guard, defence, cover, screen, shade, safety, security, shelter, safeguard, support, bulwark, protector

"He could only use his hands to shade his bald head from the blistering sun"

verb:protect from a danger, risk, or unpleasant experience.

"She pulled the construction hat over her head to shield herself from the falling debris but was unlucky and lost a thumb in the process."

Comment: You can "shield" any body part, or, really, any thing.  Nothing about it refers to specifically protecting the head.

Comment: he asked how he could shorten it, most people wouldn't shield their heads with their feet. I tried to be creative with my sentences lol